# Firefox can't get the latest java version in ubuntu 15.04 in about:configs with iceatea-8-plugin, but oracle java version verify page can

Tags: firefox, 15.04, java, openjdk

In my laptop, I have openjdk1.6, openjdk-1.7, and openjdk1.8 installed. I can see all of them through `update-alternative --config java`.

```
$update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

I also have `openjdk-7-plugin` installed. But I don't know why my firefox always shows that my latest java version is

`application/x-java-bean;jpi-version=1.7.0_50`

I already tried to [Re-initializing the plugins database](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-issues-with-plugins-fix-problems#w_re-initializing-the-plugins-database), but it doesn't work. How can I see my latest java in the browser plugin? I can see my newest java version through the [oracle java version verify page](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp).

update:

I installed the `icedtea-8-plugin` then removed the `icedtea-7-plugin`. However, the about:plugins shows that my java version is `application/x-java-bean;jpi-version=1.6.0_50`. The plugin path is correctly pointed to

```
Path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
```

The oracle java version verify page can correctly show my java version is `1.8.0_45-internal`. Does anyone have idea on how firefox discovery the java version on my laptop?

Update2:

Thanks @TrevorL for you detailed answer.

Now I removed all the `openjdk-*` packages in my system. The only thing I install is `openjdk-8-jre` and `icedtea-8-plugin`.

I confirmed all the executable and configs are located in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/`. The `mozilla-plugins.so` points to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so`. The `itweb-settings` is also pointed to correct version.

I do see firefox using the correct IcedTeaPlugin.so in the `about:plugins`. Since I only have 1 version jvm installed in my system now. I think the question should be modify to: **why IcedTeaPlugin.so in icedtea-8-plugin report java 1.6.0_50 in Firefox**?

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser_ubuntu.xml did you follow these instructions?

Comment: @dedunumax, I don't have oracle java installed on my laptop. I think the solution in the webpage only works for oracle java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Firefox use the newest Java version, which is already installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/346608/how-to-make-firefox-use-the-newest-java-version-which-is-already-installed)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE2:

On startup, Firefox references the java plugin file located in `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`, this file could be named `libjavaplugin.so` or `mozilla-javaplugin.so`

Currently, the IcedTea install from Ubuntu Software Center is IcedTea-plugin7 then its configuration results in the incorrect JVM version reported by FireFox `about:plugins` and from the Oracle browser test - despite a prior OpenJDK8 installation . A possible explanation is the way IcedTea configures itself by creating directories in `/usr/lib/jvm` with names prefixed by `java-<version>-openjdk<bits>` even if these JVMs are not installed on the machine.

- java-6-openjdk-amd64
- java-7-openjdk-amd64
- java-8-openjdk-amd64

symLinks are then created to these folders for the installed jdk and a default jdk1.7 - in the case that openjdk8 was installed.

- java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
- java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 (installed openJDK)

The symlink `itweb-settings` is configured to reference alternatives for a configuration file created in each JVM copy folder

- `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/itweb-settings`
- `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/itweb-settings`

and an executable `IcedTeaPlugin.so` at location `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64` referenced by link `mozilla-javaplugin.so`

However, the IcedTea-plugin7 does not place a configuration or executable within the copy folder of `java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/` which could explain the selection of the default / higher priority jdk7 as defined by the symlink `mozilla-javaplugin.so`.

Since, you have already installed IcedTea-plugin8 you need to confirm the configuration then attempt to select the different JVMs as you required.

1. close FireFox
2. confirm the executable and config files are located within the openJDK8 copy folder

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64`

and

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
```

3. confirm the contents of the config file references the correct JVM
4. confirm the value of symlink `itweb-settings` to the correct configuration file per JVM
   `sudo update-alternatives --display itweb-settings`
5. if this works for jdk8 then update-alternatives for each JVM

   `sudo update-alternatives --install mozilla-plugins.so <IcedTeaPlugin.so per JVM>`
   `sudo update-alternatives --install itweb-settings <itweb-settings per JVM>`
6. then configure itweb-settings as you require to use each JVM

`sudo update-alternatives --configure itweb-settings`

7. check JVM version in Firefox

****** UPDATE3 ******

`itweb-settings` configuration file references; two possible paths from the HOME directory for the `deployment.properties`

- `~/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties`
- `~/.icedtea/deployment.properties`

and a global path
`/etc/.java/.deploy/deployment.properties`

Maybe one of these files is referencing openJdk6 ?

****** UPDATE4 ******

The plugin relies on symlink priority, so ensure that jdk8 has the highest *priority*  then `update-alternatives` to `auto mode`.

And ensure that the symlink for `javaws` is defined

uninstall then re-install the v8 plugin

Comment: I don't use oracle java. The libnpjp2.so is missing in my system.

Comment: @JamieChou what is interesting with IcedTea7 is that the browser reports  a java version 1.7.0_50 even though I have never installed a Java7 for either Oracle / OpenJDK and only installed Java8 for both.

Comment: Now I only have oenjdk-8-jre installed in my system. But the about:plugins shows that my newest java version is 1.6.0_50. One more thing is that about:plugins shows that firefox already use the /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so, which is not located in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugin

Comment: @JamieChou I would suggest that you install another jvm to assist in finding a solution to your problem. Kindly post answers to the following; (1) 'ls' for path '/usr/lib/mozilla/plugin' ,(2) 'ls' for path '/usr/lib/jvm' ,(3) output from 'sudo update-alternatives --display libjavaplugin.so' ,(4) output from 'sudo update-alternatives --display mozilla-javaplugin.so'

Comment: Here they are:
(1) $ ls -l /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37 Aug 12 10:21 flashplugin-alternative.so -> /etc/alternatives/mozilla-flashplugin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   39 Aug 13 11:22 libjavaplugin.so -> /etc/alternatives/mozilla-javaplugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6096 Apr  5 19:24 librhythmbox-itms-detection-plugin.so

Comment: (2) $ ls /usr/lib/jvm/
java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64  java-6-openjdk-amd64  java-8-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64  java-7-openjdk-amd64

Comment: (3) $ sudo update-alternatives --display libjavaplugin.so
[sudo] password for jamie: 
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for libjavaplugin.so

(4)sudo update-alternatives --display mozilla-javaplugin.so
mozilla-javaplugin.so - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so - priority 1070
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so'.

Comment: Sorry for the bad looking format and thanks for the suggestion. However I don' t think the problem is the linking of the library. I can see firefox correctly use /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so. So I guess the problem is: why firefox use icedtea-8-plugin but report 1.6.0_50?

Comment: @JamieChou it is more likely the IcedTea configuration that is presenting the incorrect JVM version since you have only jdk1.5 and jdk1.8 installed (IcedTea creates the other directories) - I will UPDATE the solution post to explain further. Kindly post output from the following: `sudo update-alternatives --display itweb-settings`.

Comment: please see my reponse in the update2. Thanks for your fast and detailed suggestion.

Comment: may i suggest you change the title of this question. Of course, you could also be gracious in voting on usefull feedback

Comment: refer UPDATE 3 of my answer above. May I suggest that you remove all traces of the IcedTea plugins including configuration files then re-install v8. You can review the updated files for icedtea-8-plugin [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ebourg/openjdk/icedtea-web/changes)

Comment: I only see ~/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties in my system. The output is: deployment.jre.dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/. May I know why you don't think IcedTeaPlugin.so is not the root cause? Thank you.